# Scrapy yielding items and requesting link consecutively

Tags: python, request, scrapy, yield

my spider starts on this page https://finviz.com/screener.ashx and visits every link in the table to yield some items on the other side. This worked perfectly fine. I then wanted to add another layer of depth by having my spider visit a link on the page it initially visits like so:

```
start_urls > url > url_2
```

The spider is supposed to visit "url", yield some items along the way, then visit "url_2" and yield a few more items and then move on to the next url from the start_url.

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from dimstatistics.items import DimstatisticsItem

class StatisticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'statistics'

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ['https://finviz.com/screener.ashx? v=111&f=ind_stocksonly&r=01']

        npagesscreener = 1000

        for i in range(1, npagesscreener + 1):
            self.start_urls.append("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx? v=111&f=ind_stocksonly&r="+str(i)+"1")


    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'screener-body-table-nw')]/a/@href"):
            url = "https://www.finviz.com/" + href.extract()
            yield follow.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)


    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        item = {}

        item['statisticskey'] = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'fullview-ticker')]//text()").extract()[0]
        item['shares_outstanding'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[9]
        item['shares_float'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[21]
        item['short_float'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[33]
        item['short_ratio'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[45]
        item['institutional_ownership'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[7]
        item['institutional_transactions'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[19]
        item['employees'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[97]
        item['recommendation'] = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td/descendant::text()").extract()[133]

        yield item

        url2 = response.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'fullview-links')]//a/@href").extract()[0]

        yield response.follow(url2, callback=self.parse_dir_stats)


    def parse_dir_stats(self, response):
        item = {}

        item['effective_tax_rate_ttm_company'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate (TTM)']]/td[2]/text()").extract()
        item['effective_tax_rate_ttm_industry'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate (TTM)']]/td[3]/text()").extract()
        item['effective_tax_rate_ttm_sector'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate (TTM)']]/td[4]/text()").extract()
        item['effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_company'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate - 5 Yr. Avg.']]/td[2]/text()").extract()
        item['effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_industry'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate - 5 Yr. Avg.']]/td[3]/text()").extract()
        item['effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_sector'] = response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='Effective Tax Rate - 5 Yr. Avg.']]/td[4]/text()").extract()

        yield item
```

All of the xpaths and links are right, I just can't seem to yield anything at all now. I have a feeling there is an obvious mistake here. My first try at a more elaborate spider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

***EDIT 2

```
{'statisticskey': 'AMRB', 'shares_outstanding': '5.97M', 'shares_float': 
'5.08M', 'short_float': '0.04%', 'short_ratio': '0.63', 
'institutional_ownership': '10.50%', 'institutional_transactions': '2.74%', 
'employees': '101', 'recommendation': '2.30'}
2019-03-06 18:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AMR&ty=c&p=d&b=1>
{'statisticskey': 'AMR', 'shares_outstanding': '154.26M', 'shares_float': 
'89.29M', 'short_float': '13.99%', 'short_ratio': '4.32', 
'institutional_ownership': '0.10%', 'institutional_transactions': '-', 
'employees': '-', 'recommendation': '3.00'}
2019-03-06 18:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AMD&ty=c&p=d&b=1>
{'statisticskey': 'AMD', 'shares_outstanding': '1.00B', 'shares_float': 
'997.92M', 'short_float': '11.62%', 'short_ratio': '1.27', 
'institutional_ownership': '0.70%', 'institutional_transactions': '-83.83%', 
'employees': '10100', 'recommendation': '2.50'}
2019-03-06 18:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AMCX&ty=c&p=d&b=1>
{'statisticskey': 'AMCX', 'shares_outstanding': '54.70M', 'shares_float': 
'43.56M', 'short_float': '20.94%', 'short_ratio': '14.54', 
'institutional_ownership': '3.29%', 'institutional_transactions': '0.00%', 
'employees': '1872', 'recommendation': '3.00'}
2019-03-06 18:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_bermuda>
{'effective_tax_rate_ttm_company': [], 'effective_tax_rate_ttm_industry': 
[], 'effective_tax_rate_ttm_sector': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_company': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_industry': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_sector': []}
2019-03-06 18:45:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_china>
{'effective_tax_rate_ttm_company': [], 'effective_tax_rate_ttm_industry': 
[], 'effective_tax_rate_ttm_sector': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_company': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_industry': [], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_sector': []}
```

*** EDIT 3

Managed to actually have the spider travel to url2 and yield the items there. The problem is it only does it rarely. Most of the time it redirects to the correct link and gets nothing, or doesn't seem to redirect at all and continues on. Not really sure why there is such inconsistency here.

```
2019-03-06 20:11:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/BCACU.A>
{'effective_tax_rate_ttm_company': ['--'], 
'effective_tax_rate_ttm_industry': ['4.63'], 
'effective_tax_rate_ttm_sector': ['20.97'], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_company': ['--'], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_industry': ['3.98'], 
'effective_tax_rate_5_yr_avg_sector': ['20.77']}
```

The other thing is, I know I've managed to yield a few values on url2 succesfully though they don't appear in my CSV output. I realize this could be a export issue. I updated my code to how it is currently.

Comment: You need to yield an item directly and not the response from calling that function. If you want to yield multiple items at the same time in `parse_dir_contents` then you need to create the items in the for loop.

Comment: I've edited my code to call the item and request directly. It seems like I can yield the items in parse_dir_contents however I get the error: "[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=CPAC>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed" which is my url2 link.

Comment: A 404 error means the URL does not exist. Double check if you're extract the full, correct URL.

Comment: I've spent a few hours on this. The link is fine, I've copy pasted it from the error message into the browser and it works although for some reason it loads without javascript. But the xpaths should still work.

Comment: I changed the link and now it works fine. Although now I'm getting a new error:
"raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa" This spider still manages to yield all the items in parse_dir_contents but then throws a ValueError and doesn't seem to continue on..

Answer (score 0):

`url2` is a relative path, but `scrapy.Request` expects a full URL.

Try this:

```
yield Request(
    response.urljoin(url2),
    callback=self.parse_dir_stats)
```

Or even simpler:

```
yield response.follow(url2, callback=self.parse_dir_stats)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your input. This did seem to help. I don't get any errors while crawling now but I'm not yielding items from the url2 link. I double checked the xpaths and they work in scrapy shell however I can't seem to return the values while running my spider.

Comment: I've edited my post. Sometimes the spider seems to get to url2 and scrape but doesn't return anything. Other times it seems to not get there. Also, no columns even show up in my CSV, could this be a pipeline issue? Might have something to do with the fact that it looks like its going to the wrong link:(screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_bermuda and screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_china) not quite sure why its doing that though.

Comment: It seems like the spider doesn't actually get to the link ''http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=...' which is url2 as it doesn't show up in the log. Even though on occasion parse_dir_stats items try to be yielded.

Comment: I'm not sure why but it looks like the spider is being redirected here:
2019-03-06 18:50:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=ALACU> from <GET http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=ALACU>
Will continue to dig deeper here. BTW my middleware.py is default